# how to upload multiple files for one id in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add patients reports to their id every time they go for check.patients id are already in database.What i want to do is add his recent report and also display his previous reports.these reports can be any file like image,pdf etc.I have written code t it replaces previous file with new as i am using upload query.How do i add multiple files.

Below is the code which replaces new file with previous:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <title>Uploading</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h3 style="color:#28918f;"  align='center'>PATIENT DETAILS</h3>
  <?php
  include 'dbcon.php';

   if(isset($_GET['id']))
  {
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   $sql="SELECT * FROM upload where patient_id='$id'";
   $data = mysql_query($sql);
   $row = mysql_fetch_array($data);?>
   <table border='2' align='center'>
   <tr><th>Patient Id</th>
   <th>Doctor Id</th>
   <th>File</th></tr>
   <tr><td align='center'><?php echo $row['patient_id'];?></td>
   <td align='center'><?php  echo $row['doc_id'];?></td>
   <td align='center'><?php echo $row['file'];?></td>
   </tr>
   </table>
   <?php
   if(isset($_POST['patient_id']))
   {
   $id=$_POST['patient_id']; 
   $file = $_FILES['file']['name'];
   $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
   $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
   $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];
   $folder="uploads/";

     $new_size = $file_size/1024
     $new_file_name = strtolower($file);
     $final_file=str_replace(' ','-',$new_file_name);
     if(move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$final_file))
    {
     $sql1="UPDATE upload SET 
    file='$final_file',type='$file_type',size='$new_size' WHERE 
    patient_id='$id'";
    mysql_query($sql1);
   ?>
   <script>
   alert('successfully uploaded');
   window.location.href='fileupload.php?success';
   </script>
   <?php
   }
   else
   {
   ?>
    <script>
    alert('error while uploading file');
    window.location.href='fileupload.php?fail';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
    }
    }
    ?>
    <br /><br />
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['success']))
    {
    ?>
    <label>File Uploaded Successfully...</a></label>
    <?php
    }
    else if(isset($_GET['fail']))
    {
    ?>
    <label>Problem While File Uploading !</label>
    <?php
    }
    else
    {
    ?>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table align='center'>
   <input type="hidden" name="patient_id" value="<?php 
   if(isset($_GET['id'])){ echo $_GET['id'] ; } ?>" >
   <tr><td>Select a file</td>  <td><input type="file" name="file" />
   </td>
   <td></td><td><button type="submit"  name="btn-
   upload">upload</button></td></tr>
   </table>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: I have only read 1 line, but you are saying I have written code that replaces the previous file with the new files. Is that not your problem is you wanna keep your files from the past???

Comment: Instead of saying update have you tried insert into? This will just put a new file in instead of replacing the original collum.

Comment: Please don't use mysql_* you'll get hacked before you could say 'stack overflow ' . Either use mysqli or pdo in conjunction with prepared statements and bounded parameters. Also your upload module is weak.  Check for mime types etc. As at now,  Trojans and other harmful files can easily be uploaded.

Comment: I want to keep previous files also and upload new file .

Comment: Okay i'll mysql to mysqli.

Comment: I didnt use insert.But will it add new file along with previous  ?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**

Maintain a seperate table for reports that will help you to showing patient reports accordingly,

**reports_table:**

```
|id | file_name | file_data | patient_id | uploaded_at |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

These are the fields of reports table, here

> **file_name:** Name of the file uploaded
>
> **file_data:** Stored file path
>
> **patient_id:** Patient id
>
> **uploaded_at:** Uploaded date time

Store reports in reports_table and fetch based on patient_id and display it,

```
select * from reports_table where patient_id = patient_id
```

Answer (score 1):

To maintain the history of the previous reports, you need to create a separate table of reports with the patient id as Foreign Key.

Insert the data every time a new report is being uploaded in that new table.

You can link it to your patients view and call accordingly.